# Stuck in loop after entering any other datatype in place of int

Tags: java, exception

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the code. I am stuck in a loop after entering any other datatype in place of int.

I am trying to make this program so if i enter any other datatype than the datatype which is mentioned i will get a message and the program will ask me again to enter the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i=null;
        int j=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(j==0) {
            i=0;
            try {
                i = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(i);
                if(i>=0||i<=0){
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter only integers!");
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `j` for? You don't seem to be setting it and it is always `true`.

Comment: If `sc.nextInt();` fails you will need to get rid of the bad input by a follow up call to `sc.next()` or `sc.nextLine()`.

Comment: `if(i>=0||i<=0){` This is always true. You can delete it and just leave the `break`.

Comment: `while(true)`, `break` without any condition at the end `try`, add `sc.nextLine()` after println inside the catch

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks for both of your tips program running without any problems now.

Comment: you could write j=1; after System.out.println("Please enter only integers!"); which would break the loop and end the program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
                break;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter only integers!");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do mark as the answer if you found it helpful!